# DuckDuckGo search via the searchbar gets me the HTML version

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, firefox, javascript

If I do a search at the top right of the Tor Browser Bundle in the search bar with DuckDuckGo selected as the search provider, I am taken to the DuckDuckGo HTML page.  I don't want the HTML page, I want the javascript enabled version so I can do an image search and download and rename multiple images.duckduckgo.com files.

A DuckDuckGo search found a Redditor with pretty much the same problem: [DuckDuckGo and HTML](https://www.reddit.com/r/TOR/comments/35kvzb/duckduckgo_and_html/), though I was not able to find a solution.

I've noticed that NoScript's behavior in tbb is different than Firefox proper, does that have something to d with this behavior?  Or is this a setting of the DuckDuckGo search provider?  Is there a way to force the regular/javascript-enabled version of the site to be used?